# Picasso not loading urls including dots

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to load too many images but some of them with name ending dots `(imageOne....jpg)` are not loading.

the url is loading fine in the browser but picasso doesn't load it.

how can i fix this?

code:

```
picasso.load(getString(R.string.server_address_http) + mAlbum.getCover()).resize(300, 300)
           .centerCrop().into(mAlbumArtImageView);
```

url is a local url and it points to a normal image.

Comment: can you post your code or web url that you are trying to load image from

Comment: Enable logging in Picasso and look for an exception.

Comment: post image url as well

Comment: url is a local url and it points to a normal image. so you can't see that.